# Pull array out from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array below and I can't seem to figure out how to pull out the information from the array Team_1 and echo out the 0 - 5 values inside it.

```
 array (size=3)
      'Team_1' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '1199' (length=4)
          1 => string '1182' (length=4)
          2 => string '1105' (length=4)
          3 => string '1212' (length=4)
          4 => string '891' (length=3)
      'Team_2' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
          1 => string '' (length=0)
          2 => string '' (length=0)
          3 => string '' (length=0)
          4 => string '' (length=0)
      'Team_3' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '' (length=0)
          1 => string '' (length=0)
          2 => string '' (length=0)
          3 => string '' (length=0)
          4 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: what do you mean by pull out?? echo out?? delete it??

Comment: Sorry Andrew, Yes Echo them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is Team_1 so you can reference it directly and do a foreach loop to do the echo (you can add any html you want to echo to format the values).

```
foreach ($arr['Team_1'] as $val) {
    echo $val.'<br>';
}
```

If your intention is to loop through all teams and echo values

```
foreach ($teams as $team => $vals) {
    echo $team;
    foreach ($vals as $val) {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy heck. That was a LOT easier than I thought. Thank you so much man. Will tick as soon as post has been up for allowed time. Thanks again

Comment: Is there a way to know how many teams will be created. So instead of Team_1 

do Team_$counter  ?

Comment: You can use count($arr) to get the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output1 = $array['Team_1'][0]; // Should output 1199
echo $output1;


OR

foreach ($array['Team_1'] as $data){
 echo $data.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks SamyQc!
Was just what I was after. 

Do you know how instead of doing ['Team_1'] I can do ['Team_'.$counter] ?